# RxJava on error perform onErrorResumeNext() but also take some action

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

While iterating and fetching web responses the chain stops when it encounters an error.

I used .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()) to keep the iteration going but want to do some error handling too. How can this be done?

```
                    .getRepos()
                    .flatMap { itemList ->
                        //fetches all repos      
                        Observable.fromIterable(itemList)
                    }
                    .concatMapEager { githubItem ->
                        //fetches commits of each repos 
                        networkModule.getCommits().map { commitItem ->

                            dataBaseModule.insertRepo(commitItem)
                        }.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()) 
  //here I want to take some action instead of just passing an empty observable
                    }
```

Comment: You could use the `doOnError()` operator to perform an error action. Put it before the `onErrorResumeNext()` operator.

Comment: thanks this works! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `doOnError()` operator just before the `onErrorResumeNext()` to perform an action.

```
...
.doOnError( error -> {} )
.onErrorResumeNext( Observable.empty() )
...
```